# Change the size of header image in all posts in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have problems changing the size of the firts image i see in every post, how can i do it? I am using a WordPress Theme, Tortuga1.
I want to change the size of all the header images in all posts i already have

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I supose you are using some like this:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'large', array( 'class' => 'alignleft' ) );
```

Now try this:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'large','style=max-width:100%;height:auto;');
```

As you see CSS is used to manipulate the size of the image.
Remember use the correct size of attachment (thumbnail, medium, large, full) to show a correct density of the image. This function doesn't need echo.

*this method is not useful if your theme supports srcset attribute.